# Please help with "gone to their account elsewhere"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the highlighted phrase?

> Whereas, the world would do well to reflect, that injustice is in itself, to every generous and properly constituted mind, an injury, of all others the most insufferable, the most torturing, and the most hard to bear; **and that many clear consciences have gone to their account elsewhere**, and many sound hearts have broken, because of this very reason; the knowledge of their own deserts only aggravating their sufferings, and rendering them the less endurable.”

Comment: It would help if you included some more context  and described what parts you don't understand.

Comment: I don’t understand the word account in this

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please give us the whole sentence or the source of the quotation. Without that information your question cannot be answered and is likely to be closed. Please read the site help guide to see how to ask questions.

Comment: and that many clear consciences have gone to their account elsewhere, and many sound hearts have broken, because of this very reason; the knowledge of their own deserts only aggravating their sufferings, and rendering them the less endurable.”

From the ‘ old curiosity Shop’

Comment: Since it begins with 'and', that clearly isn't the whole sentence. Also, which chapter of _The Old Curiosity Shop_?

Comment: Whereas, the world would do well to reflect, that injustice is in itself, to every generous and properly constituted mind, an injury, of all others the most insufferable, the most torturing, and the most hard to bear; and that many clear consciences have gone to their account elsewhere, and many sound hearts have broken, because of this very reason; the knowledge of their own deserts only aggravating their sufferings, and rendering them the less endurable.”


From chapter 61

Answer (score 1):

> Whereas, the world would do well to reflect, that injustice is … the most hard to bear; and that **many clear consciences have gone to their account elsewhere,** and many sound hearts have broken.”

and that many clear consciences have **gone to their account** elsewhere = and that many people with clear consciences **have died**

OED

> 7. In Christian theology: **the final reckoning at the judgement seat of God. Frequently in last (also final) account.** Now rare. -> **to go to one's account and similar phrases: to die.**

> 1899   ‘A. Hope’ Prisoner of Zenda xix. 253   *I had but to raise my revolver, and I sent him to his account with his sins on his head.*

Comment: Thank you all you helped me a lot

Answer (score -1):

It means that they died. They "reckoned their account," which means that they paid what they owed. So the people Dickens mentions in the quotation you included settled their affairs before they died.

Comment: Are you talking about a spiritual or physical payment?

Comment: I agree that they died, but there is no reference to them settling their affairs, either literally or metaphorically. Except that they may have been judged in the afterlife.